# Is there a way to permanently set the font and window size in PuTTY?

Tags: ssh, putty, settings

When I log in with PuTTY, I always have to:

- change settings
- appearance
- font
- change
- 8
- resize window

so that I can see enough text to work with the log files.

I don't see where I can save these settings to my saved session. Is this possible?

[image]

---

### Answer:

So the answer is click on change settings, change everything but then you have to also click on session the name again and save, thanks David:

[image]

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you can also save changes to the Default Settings session, which will then be applied to all new sessions you create.  You need never see that horrible default font again :)

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/12295/how-to-make-putty-settings-persistent

Comment: @ColinPickard I start PuTTY via CLI (no sessions). So it's great that there is a general solution.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to go "Change Settings -> Window" and set it there.
Do the same under Appearance for the font and size.

[image: Change Settings menu item]

Then go back to the session and save it.

[image: PuTTY Reconfiguration dialog]

Comment: The link is dodgy but the answer seems correct.

Comment: This answer worked for me, the confirmed one did not

Answer (score 30):

Once you are done with your appearance and font settings save that to `Default Settings` session. This will help all your next session to open with the default settings you saved. Otherwise, you need to do this for every new server you added other than the saved ones.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the "Save" button saves information from other tabs, even though there is no clear visual indication of this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple saved sessions and you wish to change them all at once, there is a way.

1. Open the Windows registry editor by running `regedit.exe` (requires privilege escalation).
2. Navigate to the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY`
3. Right click on the `PuTTY` registry key and choose Export. Place the file wherever you please. Name it something like `putty.reg`. **Very important, make sure you have only exported this one key, and not the entire registry.** You might like to place this .reg file in Dropbox or other cloud storage as a backup, or to copy your session info to other machines.
4. I recommend now making a duplicate of the original file (in Explorer, copy then paste in-place) for diffing or other comparison before you load it back in.
5. Open `putty.reg`. Use search/replace to fix entries. If certain sessions do not contain the overrides from default you desire, add them.
6. Save `putty.reg`.
7. For safety, I recommend using a diff tool to compare `putty.reg` with the copy you made to ensure you didn't change anything you did not intend to.
8. Finally, double-click `putty.reg` in Explorer to overwrite the existing registry settings.

Comment: Actually it's easier: The Sessions are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions`, and the font is stored in `Font` there.

Answer (score 1):

Other things that I change are scroll back buffer size (mine is 32k) and logging. This can be very handy in the event of a crash, or just in case it overflows that buffer.  I use the portableapps version of putty, and often have as many as 6 windows open, with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

*This works with Kitty Portable, I don't know if it applies to Putty Portable:*

I had 51 preconfigured sessions and wanted to change window size for all of them. There is no settings option to achieve this, but you can do this:

- Get a text editor that can search and replace in files ([PsPad](http://www.pspad.com) / [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), ...)
- Search and replace in all configuration files in this folder:
  `C:\[Kitty/Putty Installation directory]\Sessions\`
- Examples:

  - For window height, change `TermHeight\24\` to `TermHeight\40\`
  - For window width, change `TermWidth\80\` to `TermWidth\120\`
  - ... and so on. Font is `Font\<Fontname>`, Font size is `FontHeight\10` ...

Needless to say Putty might be installed on another drive and you are allowed to choose your own values.

Comment: It appears you are using KiTTY, which is a fork of PuTTY. KiTTY may store its session on disk, but PuTTY stores them in the Windows Registry. I believe the portable version of PuTTY, which is launched with a different .exe, will persist the session info to disk on exit.

Comment: You are right - I use Kitty Portable. So the difference is probably based on the protable alternative. I'll edit my answer to make that clear.

Answer (score -2):

Actually it's very simple:

1. click on 'Session', Load desired one (click on "LOAD" button)
2. click on 'Window', adjust then desired values within 'Appearance', 'Colours',..
3. click again on 'Session', and click on "SAVE" button!

It's ready! 
Values are saved to your desired session.

If want to do this as permanent for the - Default session, click on it and do the above. Each saved session should be adjust separately!

BR,
Miro

Comment: This answer has already been given.

Comment: Yes, what's different from https://serverfault.com/a/52070/407952?